# Нумерация вывода в python

Tags: python, вывод

Возможно глупый вопрос, есть вывод в питоне формата множества строк, нужно сделать так чтобы у всех строк была нумерация
1.
2.
3.
И т.д
Думал сделать это через цикл while но не получилось

Comment: Добавляйте ваш **код прямо в вопрос**. Это можно сделать разными способами, но это зависит от того, что вы вообще делаете, а без кода непонятно. Можно использовать `enumerate`, например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте enumerate

```
strings=['str1', 'str2', 'str3']

#если надо вывести в консоль
for num, st in enumerate(strings, 1):
    print(f'{num}. {st}') 

#если надо создать лист строк
lis=[]
for num, st in enumerate(strings, 1):
    lis.append(f'{num}. {st}') 

#если надо запихнуть все в 1 строку 
endstr=''
for num, st in enumerate(strings, 1):
    endstr+=f'{num}. {st}\n'
```

Comment: enumerate(strings. 1):

Comment: Спасибки, забыл об этом)